# Passing arguments on top of those passed by trigger() in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have a method that passes up an argument in a nested view in Backbone, like such:

```
page.get('condition') ? this.trigger('someEvent', object) : this.trigger('someOtherEvent', object);
```

As I understand it, this code will pass object to '`someEvent`' or '`someOtherEvent`' as the first argument to the callback specified in the listener for that event.

My listener (in the parent view file) looks like:

```
this.parentView.on('someEvent', this.someFunction('extraArgument'), this);
```

By default, if the second parameter was just `this.someFunction`, I assume that the first argument to that function would be `object`.
My issue is that I want to pass '`extraArgument`' in addition to the implicitly passed object.

As such, I structure the signature of `this.someFunction` like this:

```
someFunction: function(object, extraArg) {
    ...
}
```

However, debug statements within the function reveal that `object` is in fact the `extraArgument` I passed manually, and that `extraArg` is  undefined in the scope of the function. How can I pass the `extraArgument` without overwriting the argument passed up from the child view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say this:

```
this.parentView.on('someEvent', this.someFunction('extraArgument'), this);
```

you're calling `this.someFunction` right there when the argument list for `this.parentView.on` is being built. Then whatever `this.someFunction('extraArgument')` returns is bound as the callback for the `'someEvent'` event. Your `someFunction` probably doesn't return a function so this `on` call won't do anything useful.

Sounds like you want to partial evaluate `this.someFunction` so that you create a new function that is just like `this.someFunction` but the first argument is always `'extraArgument'`. Underscore offers [`_.partial`](http://underscorejs.org/#partial) for just that purpose:

> **partial** `_.partial(function, *arguments)`
>
> Partially apply a function by filling in any number of its **arguments**, without changing its dynamic `this` value.

So you'd say:

```
this.parentView.on(
    'someEvent',
    _(this.someFunction).partial('extraArgument'),
    this
);
```

You can also use [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) for this if you want to set the `this` along the way.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `_.partial(this.someFunction, 'extraArgument')`?

Comment: @Jack: `_.f(x)` and `_(x).f()` are equivalent, I tend to use `_(x).f()` because it reads better to me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out I didn't know that. Does it mention this somewhere in the underscore.js documentation?

Comment: @Jack: No worries, Backbone and Underscore are full of little things like this that are only mentioned in passing somewhere else, I tend to find them by reading the source code :)

Comment: I learn every day that I have no idea how Backbone works...thanks man!